# Java Reference Error

Tags: java

I am implementing a ray tracer and am having trouble with basic Java references :/ I have been staring at this for a while and I can't see the problem...

```
IntersectResult ir = new IntersectResult();
root.intersect(ray, ir);

if(r.material!=null)
    System.out.println(result.material.diffuse);
// Doesn't print at all!!

// in my Node Class...
@Override
public void intersect(Ray ray, IntersectResult result) {

    IntersectResult i = new IntersectResult();
    for (Intersectable child:children){
        child.intersect(ray, i);
        if (result.t>i.t)
            result = new IntersectResult(i);
    }
    if(result.material!=null)
    System.out.println(result.material.diffuse); // prints correctly!
}
```

Basically my question is why is result.material null after the intersect method call when the print statements within the method call show that it is not?

Comment: where is r declared? Also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) question might help.

Comment: What is `r.material` referring to? Do you happen to mean `ir`? Also, shouldn't the `system.out.println` reference `ir` as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic case of how the "pass-by-value" approach works and it is not specific to the code in question.

With respect to the latter, the `ir` reference passed to the `intersect()` method is redirected by the statement

```
result = new IntersectResult(i);
```

So, whenever the above statement is executed, the `material` object created is not saved in the original `material` variable, but to a local one, which is lost after the `intersect` method returns.

If you want to propagate that change, make the `intersect()` method always return the `result` object at its end and change the statement at the start of the code to

```
ir = root.intersect(ray, ir);
```

and correct the typo in the following `if` statement (it is `ir.material`, not `r.material`).